# jQuery UI icons don't render correctly in table

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I'm having some serious issues with the jQuery UI icons and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I am using a custom jQuery UI css file generated from Themeroller. Here is the HTML I am using for the icons:

```
 <span class="expandDescription ui-state-default ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>
```

This works fine but when I put it into a table, everything goes haywire and I end up with what you see below:

[image: Icons]

This is in IE8. It doesn't work much better in Chrome so I beleive something is up. Here is the actual HTML for the column:

```
    <td>

          <span class="expandDescription ui-state-default ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>
        </td>
```

How can I use the icons in a table and get them to render correctly? The crazier thing is that they work in a `th` but not in a `td`. Any thoughts?

Comment: If they work in a th but not td, you've definitely got something going on with your td's css.They're built using background position, do you have anything that controls the position of backgrounds on spans in tds? Anything with `.expandDescription span` bgs?

Comment: @MetalFrog you're right. It wasn't on the expand tag but I had some padding on the column that seems to be breaking the icons. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, that'll do it. Anything that changes the size of the span will throw it off.

Comment: Good to know. Put your comment in an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQueryUI icons are built using specific sizes and the background position of a sprite. Any CSS that augments the size of the icon container will throw off which image is displayed.

Check conflicting CSS that shifts background position, or add extra size through padding.